# Stripe subscription - allows up to n entities created

Tags: stripe-payments

To clarify, this is a question for Stripe (an online payment processing app) API.

I want to limit the quantity of created entities of shipments on my app depending on the subscription. So, lets say I have subscription #1, the user is allowed to create a maximum of 100 shipment entries. subscription #2, a maximum of 200 shipments created.

I want to also be able to increment the quantity of shipment created through my POST shipment endpoint. And once the user has attained the maximum of his plan. He isn't allowed to create more, until his next payment cycle.

I do not have any code to show since it is just a API problem, but from what I get from the docs. Is this possible?

I would appreciate any kind of answers, feedbacks, or suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes

You can use the Stripe API to retrieve the user's subscription plan, then use that information to set limits on the number of sends that can be created. You can also use the Stripe API to increment the quantity of shipments created when the user makes a POST request to your shipping endpoint.

You can use the Stripe API to check the user's subscription plan, then then check the plan_id and compare it to the limit you set, if it matches, you can allow the user to create the send , otherwise you can return an error message.

Also great to keep track of the number of sends created for each user, the Stripe API can be used to retrieve the current number of sends for a user and then increment it when a new send is created.

Overall, it's possible to accomplish what you're looking for using the Stripe API.

Comment: So to keep track of the quantity created, I can use this https://stripe.com/docs/api/usage_records/create ?  I can increment the quantity in usage record it seems

Comment: Yes, that's exactly, the Stripe API is very complete and well documented